# XSLT Force Time Zone

Tags: 2013, xslt, content-query-web-part, timezone

Using XSLT, is there a way to show the time for a specific time-zone?

e.g.

```
Resolved: <xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:FormatDate(@ResolvedDate, 3081, 2, [TimeZone])"/>
```